# Configuring SSL on wildfly 8.2 with keystore without password

Tags: ssl, wildfly, wildfly-8, application-server

I'm have a keystore with the password is empty and i'm trying configuring this on wildfly 8.2 but this doesn't work.

I configured another server with a keystore that have a password and it works!

Some one knows if wildfly can't permit configure with a keystore without password?

The command lines i'm using is:

```
/core-service=management/security-realm=ssl-realm/:add()

/core-service=management/security-realm=ssl-realm/server-identity=ssl/:add(keystore-path=keystore.jks, keystore-relative-to=jboss.server.config.dir, keystore-password="", alias= simet)

/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https/:add(socket-binding=https, security-realm=ssl-realm)
```

I tried do this by cli command and it told me that password can't be null, then i tried change the standalone.xml and when i did this the server didn't start.

And the code that i added in my standalone.xml

```
<security-realm name="SSLRealm">
    <server-identities>
        <ssl>
            <keystore path="keystore.jks" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="" alias="serverkey" key-password=""/>
        </ssl>
    </server-identities>
</security-realm>
```

In glassfish, i used to use a key without password. In wildfly is it not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry. I was wrong:

The password was not empty. The password was the default password  "changeit".

Then, I learned that we don't need password to run this command:

```
keytool -list -v -alias myaliaskey -keystore keystore.jks
```

How I used the above command without password, I thought that password was empty , but not.